# Monkey patch django.util.cache function

Tags: python, django, caching, monkeypatching

I'm having issues figuring out how to monkey patch a few functions in `django.util.cache`.  I don't want to write my own caching middleware, I just want keys that are a little easier to swallow.  The `make_key` property on cache backends doesn't cut it either for my use case.

I've tried adding

```
from django.utils.cache import _generate_cache_key, _generate_cache_header_key
from spark_core import middleware

_generate_cache_key = middleware._generate_cache_key
_generate_cache_header_key = middleware._generate_cache_header_key
```

at the bottom of my `settings.py` file, but didn't have any luck with that.  I'm using the per-site cache.

Comment: what is wrong with subclassing your cache backend and override `make_key` method?

Comment: By the time `make_key` is called by the backend, `_generate_cache_key` has already been called.

Comment: I'm not sure where exacly `_generate_cache_key` is used but try to just subclass your cache backend and override `make_key` method.

Comment: I did that, and the `key` value that is passed into `make_key` is a value that is generated by `_generate_cache_key`.  It doesn't pass any information along with how it generated the key (path, args, etc) so I can't just override `make_key` to customize the key because I don't have access to the information I need within it.

Comment: I think that importing django code in settings.py is not a great idea, as various djnago modules rely on settings.py been loaded to work. Better to put this in ``models.py`` file.